# Google Custom Search for getting search results of USA LinkedIn site

Tags: google, linkedin

In Google I can search LinkedIn profiles for specific country, e.g. if I want to search project managers from Canada only then custom Google search would be:

```
project manager site:ca.linkedin.com
```

Can anyone please tell me how to search profiles from USA only.

Comment: note that you can use `-site:example.xy` to remove results from `example.xy`.

Answer (score 3):

Why use Google for something that exists on the site itself?
Go to this url:
http://www.linkedin.com/search?trk=advsrch
to get this page.

[image: linkedin advanced search]

Comment: Problem is that linkedin search only shows designation not name of users untill and unless they were in your connect list or they are part of any of your joined group.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
project manager site:us.linkedin.com
```